React Native Custom BottomSheet with nested ScrollView
I have a problem. I want to create a fully custom bottom sheet with scroll indexing without using third-party libraries. The bottom sheet in the code I created works but doesn't function like it does in the video. When I scroll to the top, I should be able to lift my finger from the pan and then slide the pan down. I want this slide-down animation to be continuous and smooth like in the video. I hope you understand what I want.
*video => https://youtube.com/shorts/5yHuG0Y3-00
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Animated, PanResponder, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const sheetMaxHeight = screenHeight-100;
const sheetMinHeight = 100;
const MAX_Y = sheetMinHeight - sheetMaxHeight;
const MIN_Y = 0;
const THRESHOLD = 60;

const useBottomSheet = () => {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
const [scrollYOffset, setScrollYOffset] = useState(0);
const scrollYOffsetRef = useRef(scrollYOffset);
const lastRef = useRef(MAX_Y);
const sheetRef = useRef(new Animated.Value(MAX_Y)).current;
const animationInProgress = useRef(false);


useEffect(() => {
scrollYOffsetRef.current = scrollYOffset;
// console.log(scrollYOffsetRef.current)
}, [scrollYOffset]);

const handleScroll = (event) => {
  setScrollYOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
}

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (_, gesture) => {
        const currentPosition = lastRef.current + gesture.dy;
        if (scrollYOffsetRef.current <= 0 && gesture.dy > 0) {
          return true;
        }
        if (currentPosition >= MIN_Y) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        sheetRef.setOffset(lastRef.current);
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (_, gesture) => {
        if (animationInProgress.current) return;
        sheetRef.setValue(gesture.dy);
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (_, gesture) => {
        sheetRef.flattenOffset();
        if (gesture.dy > 0) {
          if (gesture.dy <= THRESHOLD) {
            lastRef.current === MAX_Y ? autoSpring(MAX_Y) : autoSpring(MIN_Y);
          } else {
            autoSpring(MIN_Y);
          }
        } else {
          if (gesture.dy >= -THRESHOLD) {
            lastRef.current === MIN_Y ? autoSpring(MIN_Y) : autoSpring(MAX_Y);
          } else {
            autoSpring(MAX_Y);
          }
        }
      },
    })
  ).current;

const autoSpring = value => {
if (animationInProgress.current) return;
lastRef.current = value;
animationInProgress.current = true;
Animated.timing(sheetRef, {
  toValue: lastRef.current,
  duration:300,
  useNativeDriver: false,
}).start(()=>{
    animationInProgress.current = false;
    if(lastRef.current === MIN_Y){
    setIsOpen(false)
    }
    if(lastRef.current === MAX_Y){
    setIsOpen(true)
    }
});

};

const animatedStyles = {
height: sheetMaxHeight,
transform: [{
  translateY: sheetRef.interpolate({
    inputRange: [MAX_Y, MIN_Y],
    outputRange: [0, sheetMaxHeight-100],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  }),
}],
};

const mapBtnAnimatedStyles = {
opacity: sheetRef.interpolate({
inputRange: [MAX_Y, MIN_Y],
outputRange: [1, 0],
extrapolate: 'clamp',
}),
display: isOpen ? 'flex' : 'none',
};

const handleOpenMap = () => {
  autoSpring(MIN_Y);
}

return { 
    panResponder,
    animatedStyles,
    mapBtnAnimatedStyles,
    isOpen,
    setScrollYOffset,
    handleOpenMap,
    handleScroll
};
}

export default useBottomSheet


BottomSheetComponent

const BottomSheetComponent = () => {
  const {
    panResponder,
    animatedStyles,
    mapBtnAnimatedStyles,
    isOpen,
    setScrollYOffset,
    handleOpenMap,
    handleScroll,
  } = useBottomSheet();

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.bottomSheet, animatedStyles]} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      <ScrollView
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}
      >
        {/* Your content here */}
      </ScrollView>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.mapButton, mapBtnAnimatedStyles]}>
        {/* Map button content */}
      </Animated.View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

